# Stalled RedKiteCMS install: "The child node "db_driver" at path "fos_user" must be configured"

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I've followed their [instructions](http://redkite-labs.com/how-to-install-redkite-cms#add-redkite-cms-to-a-symfony2-existing-project) to the point where the command `php app/rkconsole redkitecms:install --env=rkcms` results in

> [Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException]
>   The child node "db_driver" at path "fos_user" must be configured.

Yet app/config/config.yml contains:

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Vol\VolBundle\Entity\Person
```

and the installation appears to have otherwise rounded up the usual suspects.

Comment: Two thoughts - In the AppKernel, does FOSUser come before RedKite?  Second - Try clearing the cache and you may have to comment out the RedKite bundle so clearing works.

Comment: FOSUser appears before RedKite.  Cache (frequently) cleared.  Error remains and is independent of position of FOSUserBundle in AppKernel.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am told otherwise, this error occurs because RedKiteCMS [does NOT support Doctrine](https://github.com/redkite-labs/RedKiteCmsBundle/issues/2).  So for applications built with Doctrine, RedKite does not provide a CMS solution.